# Is the identity function the only solution for $f(a^x)=a^{f(x)}$?

Tags: functional-equations

I was trying to solve

$$ f(a^x)=a^{f(x)} $$ for any $a,x$ .

with $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(\cdot)$ ranging where the math does not break down on real line (for example it breaks at $f(x)<0$ and $a=2n+1$ with $n$ as a natural number).

This below is what I've tried:

Take $x=1$ so $f(a)=a^{f(1)}$ as $a$ is real as $x$ does so $f(x)=x^{f(1)}$, then $f(x)=x^{c}$ but $f(a^x)=(a^x)^c$ not $f(a^{x})=a^{x^c}$ (by $f(a^x)=a^{f(x)}$). We might think that $a^{x^{c}}=a^{xc}$ holds for some $c$ so we let know what $c$ is, we have $a^{x^c}$ must be $a^{xc}$  so $a^{x^c}=a^{xc}$ implies to $x^{c}\ln a=xc\ln a$ then $x^c=xc$ so $c$ as constant may be $c=1$ then $f(x)=x$. When I made $a^{x^c}=a^{xc}$ in order to find $c$ have I got loss of generality? Is $f = \operatorname{id}$ the only solution?

Comment: I took the liberty to format your question. Hope this is to your liking, and if otherwise, please feel free to make any further changes :)

Comment: Your quantifiers are not clear.  So you mean $\forall a\;\forall x\; f(a^x)=a^{f(x)}$ ... if not, say what you do mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No! Try $f(x)=a^x$. (Assuming $a$ is fixed and $x$ is variable, see the comments.)

For that matter, the functions $f(x)=a^{a^x}$ and $f(x)=a^{a^{a^x}}$ etc. should also work.

Comment: How about $\forall a > 0 \, \forall x > 0 \; a^{f(x)} = f(a^x)$?

Comment: how would I prove that

Comment: In that case your proof can be adjusted to show that $f(x) = x$ is the only solution. You already have $x^c = cx$ for all positive $x$ which implies $c = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

$$ f(a^x) = a^{f(x)} $$

holds for any $a > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for each $a > 0$,

$$ f(a) = f(a^1) = a^{f(1)} = a^{f(1^0)} = a^{1^{f(0)}} = a. $$

Then plugging $a = e^x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$ e^x = f(e^x) = e^{f(x)}. $$

This implies that $f(x) = x$.