# All solutions for $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ on $f$

Tags: functional-equations

This problem is a general case for [Is the identity function the only solution for $f(a^x)=a^{f(x)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466996/is-the-identity-function-the-only-solution-for-fax-afx/4467016#4467016)

This functional equation $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$, $f,g$ invertible, get $f$ over where $x$ is, for example $f(e^x)=e^{f(x)}$, $f(\sqrt{x})=\sqrt{f(x)}$,...., I find out some solutions as:

- $f(x)=g(x)$
- $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$
- $f(x)=x$
- $f(x)=g(g(g(...g(x))))$

I'd like to know if there is any another solution for that and list all solutions.

Comment: All of your solutions actually express $f(x) = g^k(x)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $f(x)=e^{x},$ you don't have $\sqrt{e^x}=e^{\sqrt x}.$ What were you trying to say with the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ statement?

Comment: We would need to know something about $g$.  In the extremes, $g(x) = 0$ only requires $f(0) = 0$, and $g(x) = x$ has no restrictions at all on $f$.

Comment: The simple case of $g(x)=x+1$ gives us functions $g$ such that $g(x)-x$ is periodic with period $1.$ There are lot of such functions.

Comment: Wait, which is the input function to the question? Is $f$ the given and $g$ unknown? What do you mean by "get $f$ into where $x$ is,...?"

Comment: $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$, as well as $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=x^m$ also work.

Comment: See [In which cases are $(f\circ g)(x) = (g\circ f)(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645367/in-which-cases-are-f-circ-gx-g-circ-fx). For polynomials in particular, see the accepted answer under [When functions commute under composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/when-functions-commute-under-composition).

Comment: Not common to have this happen with entire functions. Look up the obituary of Baker, https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-london-mathematical-society/article/irvine-noel-baker-19322001/A152B474E66B853EAB26923FCB1BDB85   Also discussed in KCG,   or *Iterative Functional Equations* by Kuczma, Choczewski, Ger.   Right, I forgot the name: permutable functions.